# Not able to get the next and prev button value in .NET Core using asp-route-data

Tags: asp.net-core

This is the sample code for `.cshtml`:

```
<li>
    <a asp-route-currentPage="@(Model.CurrentPage -1)"
       class="page-link" aria-label="Next">
       <span aria-hidden="true"><</span>
       <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
</li>

 <li>
     <a asp-route-currentPage="@Model.TotalResults[0]"
        class="page-link" aria-label="Last">
        <span aria-hidden="true">>|</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Last</span>
     </a>
 </li>
```

[image]

When I click next or previous button it's not adding or minus the current page value.

Is there is any way to solve it? Please let me know. Thanks in advance

```
public int CurrentPage { get; set; } = 1;
public int Count { get; set; }
public int PageSize { get; set; } = 5;

public int TotalPages => (int)Math.Ceiling(decimal.Divide(Count, PageSize));

public bool EnablePrevious => CurrentPage > 1;
public bool EnableNext => CurrentPage < TotalPages;

public dynamic TotalResults;

public void OnGet(int CurrentPage)
{
    if (CurrentPage == 0)
    {
        CurrentPage = 1;         
    }

    ViewData["Title"] = "Transactions List";
    Transactions = GetTransactions(CurrentPage);       
}
```

Comment: Is the page refreshing? Is it hitting the appropriate Action with correct values? ... Also, please show us your Action.

Comment: page is refreshing while clicking the prev / next button but onget method not getting  the increased page value

Comment: 1. Show us the *Next* button  as well. 2. Show us the code how you handle OnGet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of your `OnGet` method, you are not updating the `CurrentPage` value with the new one.

```
public void OnGet(int CurrentPage)
{
    ...
    this.CurrentPage = CurrentPage; // Added this
    ... 
}
```